# link recognised as a link but no click possible towards anchor inside one page website

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

the code below is not working as it should:

```
   <!--/Portfolio Item -->
   <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); width: 337px; opacity: 1;" class="portfolio-item one-four  2019 thriller langverhaal isotope-item">
   <div class="portfolio_img"><a href="#Wreed2"><img src="img/wreed_cover_n2.jpg" alt="coverfoto Wreed met boksbeugel" width="147" height="208" class="img-square delay-03s animated wow zoomIn"></a></div>
   </div>
   <!--/Portfolio Item -->
```

The link is recognised as a link, but when clicking it does nothing. There is ‘section id=“#Wreed2” in the webpage, and other links are working, but this link inside this portfolio Item (Bootstrap template) does nothing, other than showing a hand indicating it is a link. Anyone any ideas?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: please include your code ...

Comment: Especially the `href`

Comment: sorry, I thought I had entered it correctly, the code should be visible now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely what are you expecting. If the `<a href = ""` starts with a `#` it will link to an id in the html. Not a new website. So it won't work if there is no tag with an id of `#Wreed2`

Comment: That's exactly what it is supposed to do. It links to the code with id "#Wreed2".

Comment: But is there another tag with the id of ``#Wreed2``

Comment: There is the following : <section id="Wreed2" name="Wreed2">  So the tag is there. But if I add the # to it, it does not work either and the link I have in another part of the webpage is not working anymore either. I'm lost...